# Junction Box - Safe for Chandelier and is Tannish Wire the White/Neutral?

Tags: lighting

Yesterday, I accidentally bumped the chandelier in my dining room, and noticed it knocked the trim piece that sits tight to the ceiling loose.  That made me realize the existing chandelier didn't look to be held in place very securely, so I took it down, as we intended on replacing it soon anyway.  I believe this was due to poor installation by a previous owner and/or a missing washer on the threaded piece that helps hold that in place.  Anyway, before buying a new one, I want to ensure two things:  that the box I have is suitable for hanging a chandelier up to 50 lbs and secondly, is the tannish colored wire actually a discolored white/neutral wire, or what should the wire opposite the black wire be used for?  Please note that one of the pictures shows the state prior to removing the existing chandelier.  Thanks for the assistance.

[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: while it is disconnected you will want to cap each wire separately to prevent shorts

Comment: The strap for holding the fixture up is in the correct holes. In the pic the screws holding the strap are supposed to be in the heavy tubes. The tubes are rated for holding heavy weight, but the tabs are only for light weight. Some people mistakenly use the boxes without the tubes and secure a heavy load with screws in those tabs.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're just saying to make sure I hang the new fixture using the circular tubes (the ones in use in the first picture that's holding the old fixture) rather than the thinner tabs, right?

Comment: Yes. The strap for holding the fixture up is in the correct holes. In the pic the screws holding the strap are supposed to be in the heavy tubes. The tubes are rated for holding heavy weight, but the tabs are only for light weight. Some people mistakenly use the boxes without the tubes and secure a heavy load with screws in those tabs. Also note that the tubes are positioned so that they are close to the ceiling joist. This reduces the torque on the ceiling box and the bending moment on the metal box.

Answer (score 5):

The “tanish” colored wire is the neutral. It used to be white but with age snd heat the color in no longer white.

Connecting the wires for the new chandelier should be white to white and black to black and the grounds together. And at the box since it is metal.

As for the box it would be stamped I can barely see the UL listing but the information should be on that tag. Standard boxes usually just have the stamped UL. So that may be a fan rated box.

Verification of the mounting is the next step, I have found fan rated boxes for 50 or 70 lbs that were not anchored when installed and a new home owner put a large fan in and it came down while running, a heavy chandelier could have the same happen if not properly mounted even if the box is rated.

Comment: Thank you!  I took a look at the UL label (nice catch), and it's rated for 150 lbs.  One last question - since I don't have a ground wire from the box (just the green screw), does the ground wire from the new chandelier just tuck under the screw, or what do you do when there is no ground wire from the box?

Comment: I've seen a few fallen chandeliers  in my day. good point.+1

Comment: I thought I saw a ground but if not put the one for the chandelier on that screw there may be an external ground wire you never know, I don’t worry about lighting as much as other things if the frame work is plastic or non conductive it may not even have a ground on the new fixture but probably will at aprox 50 lbs. I think the ground was from the original fixture, ground wires should be under the green screw on the box or support bracket, not on the mounting screws. But that’s me being picky like I am with apprentices.

Comment: Thanks again.  Unless I'm missing something, I only see two wires - the black one and the tan colored one that used to be white.

Comment: You are correct I had seen the original fixture and the improperly ground attachment.